# Why is devenv (VS2015) continuously reading huge files?

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I'm using VS2015, and noticed it getting unresponsive in recent weeks. It freezes for a few seconds on saving source files, sometimes waits minutes for builds to start, and builds very slowly with low CPU use. Restarts haven't helped. Finally I got procmon onto it and found that devenv.exe is continuously reading some large test files I have stored on my HDD.  These files are not part of my solution, and are in no way devenv's business.  It just reads sequentially, tens of MB per second, file after file, and as soon as it gets to the end (several GB) it seems to start reading them all again.  No wonder it is unresponsive, as it keeps swapping itself out to virtual memory!

While I don't normally consider myself one of the tin-foil hat brigade, I'm concerned at this, especially given the ever tighter integration of VS with MS user accounts and cloud services.  Is there an innocent explanation?

Comment: What kind of projects?

Comment: C and C++ projects.

Comment: My Visual Studio is fast. I don't know what the large files your Visual Studio is reading.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be the Git source-control "plug-in" which is built into Visual Studio. When Visual Studio detects that your project is inside a Git repo, it activates the plug-in, which seems to read its way through every file in the repo.  It seems like anytime there is a change (eg. saving a source file) the plug-in reads its way through every file in the repo all over again. I guess it is calculating hashes or something. But there's obviously no caching of results, and it's reading files which are not even under version control. So basically, it is shitty design by Microsoft. An apology would be wonderful.

To disable it, go to Tools->Options, Source Control, Plug-in Selection, and set "Current source control plug-in" to "None". The problem and lagginess is immediately resolved.